# C two linked-list search

Tags: c, search, linked-list

I've been trying to search common words in 2 linkedlist.

I write a simple method for this.

**Code**

```
void search(node *first1, node *first2){

while(first2 != NULL){

    while(first1 != NULL){
        if(first1 -> string == first2 -> string){
            printf("%s\n", first1 -> string );
        }

        first1 = first1 ->next;
    }

    first2 = first2 ->next;
}
}
```

first1 and first2 are headers of two file's linkedlists.

first2 first element is "**is.**". Output gives me 27 "**is.**" nothing else. And 27 is the number of element in first1 ll.

Comment: `strcmp` for strings?

Comment: Are the two lists sorted?

Comment: @EdHeal i used this now. makes no difference

Comment: @wildplasser no.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never have spaces around them.  You've not shown the node structure.  I wonder if '2 linked list' is a 'doubly-linked list' where the nodes contain both a next and a previous pointer?  The code doesn't use the previous pointer if that's what we're discussing, so for this question it can be treated as a singly-linked list, but maybe the vocabulary will help avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no they are seperated linked-lists.

Comment: Ah — OK.  I misunderstood what you're asking about.  While finding words in common, you would benefit hugely from maintaining the two lists in sorted order (with unique entries).  Then you  can make a single pass over the two lists, stepping through them in tandem (rather like the merge process for a merge sort, if you've studied that yet).  If they're not in sorted order, you have to repeatedly scan one of the lists.  It is best to repeatedly scan the shorter list in that case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you i will sort the linked-list then.

Comment: Do not edit the question after you've got answers.  I've rolled it back.  You can find the material in your edited question by going to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46624414/revisions (which is the 'edited' link above the last editor icon) — so your revision isn't lost; it just isn't visible. Please ask a new question as you were directed to do.

Comment: [stylistic] Note: using for() loops instead of while() loops would reduce the number of lines by at least two. It would also make your program more readable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After completing a `while(first1 != NULL)` loop, your `first1` pointer always points to `NULL`, so subsequent `while(first2 != NULL)` loop iterations will always find `first1 == NULL`.

To remedy this, you should hold on to `first1`'s value when entering the function:

```
void search(node *first1, node *first2){

node *first1_head = first1; // <- keep track of the first element in first1

while(first2 != NULL){
    while(first1 != NULL){
        if(first1 -> string == first2 -> string){
            printf("%s\n", first1 -> string );
        }

        first1 = first1 ->next;
    }

    first1 = first1_head; // <- restore first1 to point to its first element
    first2 = first2 ->next;
}
```

In addition, depending on `string`'s type, you should use a proper string comparison function.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, i have one question. I used strcmp but the problem still same. It gives 891 "**is.**" means that 27*33. 33 is the number of element in second linked-list. Somehow program always finds same element which "**is.**" is not a common word. There is something wrong in the if statement.

Comment: @M.Aktas: You'd need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) for us to be able to see how you're creating the lists and what's going on.  You can ask a new question with the MCVE, showing what you've learned from this one.  As pointed out in this answer, you need to use `strcmp()` or similar to compare strings; using `first1->string == first2->string` checks whether the pointers point to the same place (and is arguably undefined behaviour if they don't, but that's a "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin" paradox that doesn't need to concern youright now).

Comment: @M.Aktas As mentioned right above this comment, you'd need to show us how you've defined `node` as well as how you've added elements to `first1` and `first2`, preferably in a new question for clarity.

Comment: You were told not to mangle your question, @M.Aktas.  That was a serious suggestion — nay, command.  Don't change the question after you've got an answer, especially after you've accepted the answer.   Ask a new question! Please read the [Ask] and [About] pages again.  And do not create chameleon questions!